# Accessing the closing event delegate on specific contact page in VSTO 2010 Outlook Add-in

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, vsto

I have access to some proprietary WPF (C#) code that creates an add-in on the contacts page in 2010 Outlook. When I open a specific contact in Outlook, I found that closing that specific contact using the red X by passes my business logic.

In 2010 Outlook, how do I access the closing event delegate once I double click on a specific contact? I would like to direct that closing event to an ICommand in my view model.

Edit: I've realized that this is a wpf application embedded in a winform. I think that I just need access to the application level closing event delegate.

Comment: If you want more information or would like to guide me towards giving the information that you need to answer this question, just ask. I am still trying to get used to the VSTO/Outlook model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/inspector-close-event-outlook) event of the Inspector class which is fired when the inspector associated with a Microsoft Outlook item is being closed. You need to track `Inspectors.NewInspector` event (set up the event handler on startup). Then when `NewInspector` fires, set the event handler for the `Inspector.Close` event on the new inspector.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at this now.